# Custom Login Page -- wp_signon Headers Already Sent?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, login, headers

As the title suggests, I'm building a custom front-end login page for users of my site. I'm using wp_signon to log the user in after their credentials have been validated, but I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyeleven\header.php:13) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 737
```

twentyeleven\header.php:13 shows this (lines above and below included):

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" <?php language_attribute(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
```

I've read a thing or two that said wp_signon must occur before any page content is created because it alters the headers, but I guess I'm not really sure how I'd use it then. Where should wp_signon go? Here's the structure of my code as it is:

```
//Retrieve submitted $_POST values.
//Check if this is the first time the form has been displayed (there is a hidden input at the end of the form that changes a boolean to false for all future submits)
//If it's not the first time, do form validation and create an array with error ID's to be displayed in the form. One of these possible errors is wrong username/password combo:
if (!get_userdatabylogin( $submitted['email'] ))
     $errors['emailIsValid'] = false;
else
{
     $user_data = get_userdatabylogin( $submitted['email'] );
     $password_hashed = $user_data->user_pass;
     if (wp_check_password($submitted['password'], $password_hashed, $user_data->ID))
     {
          $credentials = array();
          $credentials['user_login'] = $submitted['email'];
          $credentials['user_password'] = $submitted['password'];
          if (empty($submitted['rememberme']))
               $credentials['remember'] = false;
          else
               $credentials['remember'] = true;
          wp_signon($credentials, true);
     }
     else
          errors['passwordMatchesEmail'] = false;
}
//Check to see if the errors array has any flags, if so flag a variable to say errors exist
//Form code: form submits to itself
//Check error flags and display error message accordingly
//Display body of form
```

Everything works perfectly except for that `wp_signon` line. Entering the correct credentials yields the error I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to hook earlier in the request to log someone in, you can't do it from a page template because, as the error says, headers have been sent to the browser already, so it's too late at that point.

```
<?php   
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_check_login');

function my_check_login(){
    if( is_page('my-login-page') && isset($_POST['email']) ){
        // check input and
        // do my login stuff here   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. Now I just have to figure out how to get wp_redirect() to work...

Comment: @Milo  What if I want to do `wp_signon` from a plugin settings page?
See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/358622/how-to-use-wp-set-password-in-a-plugin